# More "pythonic" way of expanding list of lists to one joined list

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-3.2

This is python syntax related question... Is there *more elegant* and *more pythonic* way of doing this:

```
>>> test = [[1,2], [3,4,5], [1,2,3,4,5,6]]
>>> result = []
>>> for i in test: result += i
>>> result
[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6]
```

Join multiple list (stored inside another list) to one long list?

Comment: @AshwiniChaudhary you're right it's a duplicate, didn't occur to me to use word `flat` when searching for similar questions.

Comment: There is no inherent harm to posting a duplicate, don't worry. Sometimes it's laziness on the poster's part, but in some cases it's a case of different wording, that's why duplicated don't disappear, and instead remain open as 'pointers' to the duplicated question, which means those search terms now point to an answer.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Use the [`itertools.chain.from_iterable()`](http://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.chain.from_iterable) classmethod:

```
from itertools import chain

result = list(chain.from_iterable(test))
```

If all you need to do is iterate over the chained lists, then don't materialize it to a `list()`, just loop:

```
for elem in chain.from_iterable(test):
    print(elem, end=' ')   # prints 1 2 3 4 5 1 2 3 4 5 6
```

You can also use parameter unpacking, directly on [`itertools.chain`](http://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.chain):

```
for elem in chain(*test):
```

But do this only with a smaller list.

Comment: Do you?  I think `from_iterable` is not necessary or useful in this case.

Comment: @A.R.S.: In this case `*test` will do.

Comment: Oh, never mind, I see

Comment: `from_iterable()` makes far more sense here. Why use `*` unpacking when `from_iterable()` is designed to do the job? On a small list, there is no difference, but on a larger one, it could make a big difference.

Comment: @Lattyware: Because `test` is not a generator. Why feed the list one by one when you have it ready expanded?

Comment: @Lattyware: Hrm, yes, with a big list it'll use a copy, you have a point ther.

Comment: Yeah. It's not the end of the world, but it makes a lot more sense to just always use `chain.from_iterable()` over `*` unpacking - there is no real downside (slightly less nice syntax, but not horrific), and a potential gain. It also means the code is more flexible if it happens to take a generator or a large list tomorrow, which is always a possibility with a dynamic language like Python.